# logback custom log level handling

Tags: logback

I want to extend logback to send logs with ERROR log levels to our internal logging service (with http post and some custom parameters).

Is writing a custom logback Filter the best way to do this? The word 'filter' to me sounds more to "filter out logs".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ThresholdFilter`, that will only log messages with level given log level (or above) on a specific appender. Here is an example, on how to configure a `ThresholdFilter` for log level  ERROR. It will log all ERROR messages using the surrounding `ConsoleAppender`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<!-- ... -->
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- log messages with ERROR (and above) only -->
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd - HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{60} - %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
<!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

So you must replace the sourrounding `ConsoleAppender` with your appender implementation, which will log to your custom logging service via HTTP Post. The `ThresholdFilter` can be used as shown in the example above.

For learning how to implement your own Appender, you might want to take a look at the [simpledb-appender](http://code.google.com/p/simpledb-appender/) project, which implements a custom appender for Amazon SimpleDB.